# How can i set properly the background Image of a grouped TableView?

Tags: objective-c, uitableview

I am new at iPhone Development.

I know there are may answers related to my question but none helped me.

As per the title I have UITableView with style Grouped.
I want to set background image but I can't set it properly.

But problem is that as describe in my Screenshot.

[image]

Well i want to display my image view only area that describe by `cells` of `UITableView` (**grouped**)

**Here is my code:**

```
self.tblView = [[UITableView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 125, 320, 320) style:UITableViewStyleGrouped];

    UIImageView *bgTableImageView = [[UIImageView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,0, 320, 320)];
    bgTableImageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"bgImage.png"];

    self.tblView.backgroundColor=[UIColor clearColor];
    [self.tblView setBackgroundView:bgTableImageView];

    //self.tblView.backgroundView = nil;
   // self.tblView.opaque = NO;
    //self.tblView.bounces = NO;
    //self.tblView.scrollEnabled = YES;
    self.tblView.delegate=self;
    self.tblView.dataSource=self;
    self.tblView.separatorColor = [UIColor darkGrayColor];
    self.tblView.separatorStyle = UITableViewCellSeparatorStyleSingleLine;
    [self.view addSubview:self.tblView];
```

All the other worked fine and Properly, i have only issues of How to set background image of `UITableViewStyleGrouped`?

Answer (score 4):

Try this:

```
UIImageView *av = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(20, 20, 277, 58)];
av.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
av.opaque = NO;
av.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"categorytab1.png"];
cell.backgroundView = av;
```

Comment: OP not want to set cell's background but it want to set background of TableView with style is grouped. your code set imageview for each cell of row.

Comment: i am not want to set UIImageView as background of cell but i want to set it as background of UITableView

Comment: But, you said in added image that You want to display your image view only on cells of grouped table view. And In above comment you said that you want to have background for TableView? Clear the confusion, first.

Answer (score 3):

Use following code insatnd of use `UIImageView`.

```
self.tblView.backgroundView.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"YourImage.png"]];
```

OTherwise,

```
self.tblView.backgroundView.inputView.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"tblbg.png"]];
```

**Second  option** (*This option is helpful when you **not depend** on `UITableView` Style*)

1) change Your `UITableView` Style,  `style:UITableViewStylePlain`.
   2) Add `#import <QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h>` Framework
   3) Change frame of `UITableView` such like, `CGRectMake(10, "asYouNeed", 300, "asYouNeed")`
   4) Give rounded radius of you `UITableView`

```
self.tblView.layer.cornerRadius = 10; // set Radius as you need
```

And set `UIImageView` as  `BackGroundView` of `UITableView`. (*follow code that you have putted in This Question*)

This above step is created `UITableView` With **rounded corner**. **I Mention** here that this code is use when you not depended on `UITableView` Style, if `TableView Style:Gropped` is important for you then this option is not help for you.

Thanks :)

Answer (score 3):

First, a bit of information how table works:

1. `UITableView` has a background. This is what you see behind your cells.
2. Every cell has three special views: `contentView`, `backgroundView`, `selectedBackgroundView`.
3. The `backgroundView` is displayed under the contents of the cell, when the cell is selected, `selectedBackgroundView` is used instead.
4. Normally all your contents should go to the `contentsView`. The separation of background from content enables the table to animate the not-selected/selected transition propertly. It is also important when the cell enters editing mode - the contents are shrinked/moved and the editing controls (e.g. delete button or cell selection) can be displayed independently on contents.
5. The cell also directly contains separator view (usually 1 or 2px high view at the cell bottom, depending on `separatorStyle`). That's why the cell is always at least 1 px higher that its `contentsView`.

Second, a bit of information how grouped table works.

1. The table has a special default background. You can remove/change it using `backgroundView` and `backgroundColor`.
2. The cells in grouped table views have smaller `contentView`. The cell still has the same width as the whole table, but the `contentView` has an offset on the left and on the right (around 10 points on iPhone).
3. The `backgroundView` is modified and includes a layer drawing the borders, depending on cell position (different for first, last and middle cells). The border has the color specified by table's `separatorColor`.

Everything can be modified in your code!

One of the simplest methods how to remove the borders is setting `separatorColor` to `[UIColor clearColor]`. This will remove the cell separators, but you can add your own separator, e.g

```
cell = ...
UIView* separator = [[UIView alloc] init];
separator.backgroundColor = ...
separator.frame = CGRectMake(0.0f, table.bounds.size.width, table.rowHeight - 1.0f, 1.0f);
separator.autoresizingMask = (UIViewAutoresizingMaskFlexibleTopMargin | UIViewAutoresizingMaskFlexibleWidth);
[cell addSubview:separator]; //note we are adding it directly to the cell, not to contentsView
```

You can also use an image (`UIImageView`) for the separator, instead of a single-color view.

Another method is setting the `backgroundView` to `nil` for each cell.

Actually, you can completely ignore the `contentsView` and add everything to the cell directly. You can then customize the following cell methods to update your cell when its state changes.

```
- (void)setSelected:(BOOL)selected animated:(BOOL)animated {
    //update the cell text colors, backgrounds etc for the selected/not selected state
    //you don't have to call super
    // (the default implementation changes between backgroundView and selectedBackgroundView)
}

- (void)setHighlighted:(BOOL)highlited animated:(BOOL)animated {
    //update the cell text colors, backgrounds etc for the selected/not highlighted state
    //you don't have to call super
    // (the default implementation changes between backgroundView and selectedBackgroundView)
    //by giving empty implementation, you will block highlighting of cells
}

- (void)setEditing:(BOOL)highlited animated:(BOOL)animated {
  //you can use this method to add custom editing controls
}

- (void)willTransitionToState:(UITableViewCellStateMask)state {
  //use this method to change the layout of your contents
  //when the cells goes into one of the editing states
}

- (void)layoutSubviews {
  //update the frames of cell contents to match the new cell size
  //note that the cell doesn't have the correct size until it is added to the table,
  //this method is called when the cell already has the final size

  //you can also use this method to change the size/position of the `contentsView`
}
```

**Edit:**
To address your specific problems, the best solution is probably:

1. Remove the default `backgroundView` from the table and suplement your own background (e.g. clear color, white color, color created from pattern or a `UIImageView` to `backgroundView`.
2. Remove the default `backgroundView` from every cell and replace it by an `UIImageView`. You need three special images for first, last and middle cells.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to make your custom cell UI then Try with

```
 _tblNews.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
        _tblNews.backgroundView = nil;
        _tblNews.separatorColor = [UIColor clearColor];
        _tblNews.separatorStyle = UITableViewCellSeparatorStyleNone;
```

And create nib for your cell as you want to make your cell and load that cell in your data source method.

for load xib

```
+ (id)loadNibNamed:(NSString *)NibName {
    NSObject *cl = nil;
    if (NSClassFromString(NibName) != nil) {
        NSArray *arr = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:NibName owner:self options:nil];
        for (id cls in arr) {
            if([cls isKindOfClass:NSClassFromString(NibName)])
            {
                cl = cls;
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    return cl;
}
```

make sure in xib you set identifier for reusability of cell.
Using that u can customise cell layout easily.

Answer (score 2):

Set `UITableView` background view as **nil** to make it transparent.

```
[tableView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"backgroundImage.png"]]];
tableView.opaque = NO;
tableView.backgroundView = nil;
```

Hope it'll help you.

Answer (score 2):

Do you want like this

[image]

Here is the code :-

Setting background view of UITableView anywhere you want .I have done it in viewDidload.

```
[_tblView setBackgroundView:[[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"url.jpg"]]];
```

And set tableViewCellBackground color to transparent in cellForRowAtIndexPath

```
    static NSString *cellIdentifier=@"cellIdentifier";
UITableViewCell *cell=[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier];

if (cell ==nil) {
    cell=[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:cellIdentifier];
}
cell.backgroundColor=[UIColor clearColor];
cell.textLabel.text=@"goup styled";
return cell;
```

Answer (score 1):

Please try this,

```
UIView *backgroundView = [[UIView alloc] init];
[backgroundView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"imageName.png"]]];
```

and in the tableview, please set this property.

```
UITableView *tableView = [[UITableView alloc] init];
[tableView setBackgroundView:backgroundView];
```

Hope this works for you.